# how to throw id parameter and display detailed data based on id at listview in react native

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, native

I'm learning react native, here I have a listview that I took via the API, response results as follows:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "error": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "awb": "RJCSS1728999298839828",
            "name": "amar",
            "destination": "Bandung"
        }
    ]
}
```

here I display the data using listview which only shows the awb. I want to ask, how to throw the id parameter, when I click the listview it displays the details?

```
constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {
        dataOrigin: [],
        isLoading : true
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
      const url = 'https://example.com/get'
      fetch(url)
      .then((response)=> response.json())
      .then((responseJson)=>{
          this.setState({
              dataSource: responseJson.data,
              isLoading : false
          })
      })
      .catch((error)=>{
          console.log(error)
      })
  }

 render() {
      return (
          <List keyExtractor = {(item, index)=> index.toString()} 
          dataArray={this.state.dataSource}  
          renderRow={(item) =>
         <ListItem icon style={{marginBottom: 20,marginTop: 5}}>
             <Body>
             <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text>{item.awb}</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             </Body>
        </ListItem>
   }>
</List>
)
```

I have tried adding this

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    id={item.id} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('tracking', { id: id})}>
    <Text>{item.awb}</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

and i got an error
**Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're passing it the wrong way.Here's how you should pass it

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('tracking', { id: item.id})}>
    <Text>{item.awb}</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

and if you want to carry all the items, you can pass it like so

```
<TouchableOpacity 
   onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('tracking', {
    id: item.id, 
    item: item})}>
   <Text>{item.awb}</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```